# Cannot change src of image by JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I am trying to change src attribute after controller sent data to a view, however all my attempts have no result. A script at a View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
        autoUpload: true,
        done: function (e, data) {
            $('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
            $('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
            $('.file_size').html(data.result.size);             
            $('.file_source').attr('src', 'D:/somePhoto.jpg'); //this row does not set 'src' of <img/>
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
    });
});
</script>

<img class="file_source" src="" /> <!--src attribute is just empty--->
```

Could you tell please where I’ve made an error?
this row is not working:

```
$('.file_source').attr('src', 'D:/somePhoto.jpg'); //this row does not set 'src' of <img/>
```

The attribute 'src' of tag  is not altered to src="D:/somePhoto.jpg".
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please define "not working"? Split the calls and check the exact location. Does the instruction actual run? Inspect the HTML after the call and see if the value was modified. Does `$('.file_source')` select all the right elements?

Comment: Did you try use prop() method instead of attr() ?

Comment: @AndreiV, The attribute 'src' of tag <img/> is not altered to src="somePhoto.jpg".

Comment: Change `$('.file_source').attr('src', 'somePhoto.jpg');` to `var imgs =  $('.file_source'); debugger; imgs.attr('src', 'somePhoto.jpg');`, open the developer console and when the breakpoint is reached, check if `imgs` contains all your target elements.

Comment: @Andrei V , yes it has. nodeName="IMG". However, proved code cannot change src: $(."file_source").attr("src", "D:\1.png");

Comment: @Dissapponted, Yeah, I've tried to use prop instead attr, however there is no result.

Comment: @StepUp How are you determining that the attribute has not changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried assigning a valid image location from the web inside the image source? I am pretty sure, `D:\somePhoto.jpg` is the location at server side. If that is the case, then `javscript` does not know how to get it, because `js` runs on client side, and after you have already sent the data from controller, there is nothing it could do.

First test with an image available from web to test, such as this - http://sci8.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/test-all-the-things.jpg

So change your code to -

```
$('.file_source').attr('src', 'http://sci8.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/test-all-the-things.jpg');
```

If that works ( and I am pretty sure, it will), then you know the reason why. Just keep the `somePhoto.jpg` somewhere inside the `Content` folder of your project and use that url.

for example

```
$('.file_source').attr('src', 'http://<hostaddress>/content/image/somePhoto.jpg');
```

If you are still facing problems, please let me know.

Comment: You are extremely right! My image was at location of server side! Thank you very much!:)